# Update UI when permission is Granted

Tags: android, google-maps, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I learning kotlin and coroutines; I would like that the app zoom on my location just after i give location permission, but instead i need to close app and restart it to have zoom...

Can someone help me please ?

Here is my [code](https://github.com/Davidvgn/googleMapLocation_kotlin)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  to improve your question it will be good to provide some description of parts of your code, how it is designed, etc. Just link to some place that anyone have to inspect or download by its own risk, is not really how things work here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is when you call `fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates` when the user hasn't granted the location permission, it will fail and stop immediately. Then even if you grant permissions, it won't emit value. The only place you refresh the flow is from `onResume`, that's why reopening the app triggers the location to start to update.

You have to listen to the permission request result and trigger the Flow again:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MapFragment : SupportMapFragment() {

    private var map: GoogleMap? = null

    private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        if (permissions[Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION] == true &&
            permissions[Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION] == true) {
            onPermissionGrant()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = MapFragment()
    }

    private val viewModel by viewModels<MapViewModel>()
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        getMapAsync { googleMap ->
            map = googleMap

            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
        }
    }

    private fun onPermissionGrant() {
        viewModel.viewActionLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { latLng ->
            map?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15F))
        }
    }
}
```

One more to note is that you use Flow and convert it into LiveData to update the UI, this will keep the flow running even when the app is in the background. In this location update case, this will take unnecessary resources and may quickly drain the user's battery. Consider collecting the Flow directly from `MapFragment` so the lifecycle will stop the Flow when the app is in the background, saving the energy for user:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.locationFlow.flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED).collect { latLng ->
        map?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15F))
    }
}
```

The Flow is automatically started when the Fragment is in STARTED state and closes itself when STOPPED, you will see `awaitClose` is called to clear the callback this time.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, which works ! My problem is that I would like to respect mvvm good practices and have not any intelligence in my view... just like i was able to do in [Java](https://github.com/Davidvgn/googleMapLocation_java)

Comment: Glad I can help, if this fits your problem then you can mark and confirm my answer. This approach still respects the MVVM architecture, `Flow` is a Kotlin feature so there is no problem exposing it from the `ViewModel` to the View

Comment: I thought i was not able to have any 'if' in a view using MVMM !

Comment: Why is that? It's normal if you use `if` to check simple logic to render your UI and flow that requires a component like `Activity` to handle, like in the permission request case. Your ViewModel can define logic, but it cannot control permission request or pass Intent data and result because it's still the View's job

Comment: Oh  Ok ! Thank you for your help, i am still a newbie so there is lot of confusing things still.